# jQuery and dynamically generated table from a start and finish value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'd like to use a slider on a html form using jQuery. The slider needs values from 00:00 and 23:55 and have to handles on it for start and finish times. From the two values generated from the slide a table needs to be generated (I assume with some kind of for loop) with all the times between the start time and finish time displayed in five minute increments.

An alternative would be to have two select menus with the start and finish values (the second would have to be dynamically generated I assume so the end user can't set the finish time before the start time).

I'd prefer to have the logic in jQuery as a sizeable chuck of the application is jQuery.
If anyone could help or even suggest where to begin, I would appreciate it.

Dan

UPDATE

I've managed to get the slider working with the jQuery UI now all I need to do is take the values generated and loop through its to produce a table with all the times between the two values:

```
            var startTime;
        var endTime;
        $("#slider-range").slider({
            range: true, min: 0, max: 1439, values: [540, 1020], step:5, slide: slideTime, /*change: */
        });
        function slideTime(event, ui){
            var minutes0 = parseInt($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) % 60);
            var hours0 = parseInt($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) / 60 % 24);
            var minutes1 = parseInt($("#slider-range").slider("values", 1) % 60);
            var hours1 = parseInt($("#slider-range").slider("values", 1) / 60 % 24);
            startTime = getTime(hours0, minutes0);
            endTime = getTime(hours1, minutes1);
            $("#time").html('Opening time: ' + startTime + '<br /> Closing time: ' + endTime);
        }
        function getTime(hours, minutes) {
            
            minutes = minutes + "";
            if (hours == 12) {
                hours = 12;
            }
            if (hours > 12) {
                hours = hours  ;
            }
            if (minutes.length == 1) {
                minutes = "0" + minutes;
            }
            return hours + ":" + minutes ;
    }
    
    slideTime();
```

theres a nice little tutorial here to get this working with times:[Using a jQuery UI Slider to Select a Time Range](http://blog.marcneuwirth.com/2010/02/21/using-a-jquery-ui-slider-to-select-a-time-range/)

Now if anyone can help me to output the times in a table it would be appreciated ;-D

UPDATE AGAIN

OK this is almost done now, I've created the table from the slider and now all I want to do is pass in a value from the drop down box to the check boxes. So for example, if someone selects the third value in the list every third checkbox should be selected. I thought it would be as easy as nth-child selector but the test value of 3 doesn't seem to work

Any ideas? The source code is here and the test example here: [slider test](http://www.premiersoftware.co.uk/slider-demo3D.html), as you can see I'm trying to pass in the 3rd selected but the code doesn't work. it does if I change `$('.chx:nth-child(3)')` to `$('.chx:odd')` or `$('.chx:even')` but this wont be any good as the value is dynamically generated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var startTime;
            var endTime;
            
            $("#slider-range").slider({
                range: true, min: 0, max: 1439, values: [540, 1020], step:5, slide: slideTime, /*change: */
            });
            
            function slideTime(event, ui){
                var minutes0 = parseInt($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) % 60);
                var hours0 = parseInt($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) / 60 % 24);
                var minutes1 = parseInt($("#slider-range").slider("values", 1) % 60);
                var hours1 = parseInt($("#slider-range").slider("values", 1) / 60 % 24);
                startTime = getTime(hours0, minutes0);
                endTime = getTime(hours1, minutes1);
                $("#time").html('Opening time: ' + startTime + '<br /> Closing time: ' + endTime);
            }
            function getTime(hours, minutes) {
                minutes = minutes + "";
                if (hours == 12) {
                    hours = 12;
                }
                if (hours > 12) {
                    hours = hours  ;
                }
                if (minutes.length == 1) {
                    minutes = "0" + minutes;
                }
                return hours + ":" + minutes ;
        }
        function getTimeloop(minutesloop) {
                minutesloop = minutesloop + "";
                if (minutesloop.length == 1) {
                    minutesloop = "0" + minutesloop;
                }
                return minutesloop ;
        }   
        slideTime();
        
        $('#generateTable').click(function(){
            var startLoop = parseInt($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0));
            var endLoop = parseInt($("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));
            $('#table').remove();
            $('<table id="table"><tr><th>Times</th><th>Bookable</th><tr>').insertAfter('#generateTable');
            for(i = startLoop; i < endLoop; i+=5)
            {
                $('<tr><td>' + parseInt(i/ 60 % 24) + ':' +  getTimeloop(parseInt(i % 60)) + '</td><td><input class="chx" name="' + parseInt(i/ 60 % 24) + ':' +  getTimeloop(parseInt(i % 60)) + '" type="checkbox" value="' + parseInt(i/ 60 % 24) + ':' +  getTimeloop(parseInt(i % 60)) + '" /></td></tr>').appendTo('#table');
            }
        
    
        $('.chx:nth-child(3)').attr('checked', true);
        
    });
    });
    </script>
    <style>
        #slider-range{width:800px;}
        #slider-range,#time{margin:10px;display:block;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="slider-range"></div>
        <span id="time"></span>
    <select>
      <option value="0">05</option>
      <option value="1">10</option>
      <option value="2" selected="selected">15</option>
      <option value="3">20</option>
      <option value="4">25</option>
      <option value="5">30</option>
      <option value="6">35</option>
      <option value="7">40</option>
      <option value="8">45</option>
      <option value="9">50</option>
      <option value="10">55</option>
      <option value="11">60</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <br />
        <a id="generateTable"href="javascript:;">generate table</a>
        
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/  but it uses integer values, so, if you set the range on the slider from 0 to 1435 *(23 * 60) + 55*, with a step of 5 you could then convert into time for display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow you've done a lot of work with no answers! I'd recommend just iterating through each checkbox and using modulo arithmetic to determine whether it should be set or not. eg.

```
var i=0;
$('.chx').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('checked',(i % period==0));
    i++;
});
```

or similar. Where `period` is 1 for every checkbox, 2 for every other etc...

Comment: There's probably a more idiomatic way of doing it in jQuery but I'm not much of an expert. Where's Nick Craver when you need him?